# frequency table and group by multiple variables in r

Tags: r, count, data.table, dplyr, frequency

Folks, I need an elegant way of creating frequency count and group by multiple variables. Output should be a dataframe. I know the answer lies somewhere in using dplyr and data.table which I am still learning.
I tried this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWvk9.png) but I want to do this using dplyr and data.table.

Here is the sample data from the same link -

```
ID <- seq(1:177)
Age <- sample(c("0-15", "16-29", "30-44", "45-64", "65+"), 177, replace = TRUE)
Sex <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), 177, replace = TRUE)
Country <- sample(c("England", "Wales", "Scotland", "N. Ireland"), 177, replace = TRUE)
Health <- sample(c("Poor", "Average", "Good"), 177, replace = TRUE)
Survey <- data.frame(Age, Sex, Country, Health)
```

Here is the output I am looking for. Thanks and appreciate your help!

[image]

Comment: I am also fine with not having grand total in the dataframe but I don't want to type in the actual factor levels as part of the code as akrun is suggesting - "[, Total := Average + Good + Poor][]"

Comment: `library(tidyverse); Survey %>% count(Age, Sex, Health) %>% spread(Health, n, fill = 0)`

Comment: Thanks alistaire...tidyverse seems nice!....does it also allow count distinct, average and sum functionalities as you did in the "spread(Health,....)" by specifying n?

Comment: Sure. `count` is really a shortcut for `group_by(...) %>% summarise(n = n())`, but you can specify whatever you like. Hadley's [_R for Data Science_](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html) is a good starting point.

Comment: I challenge the closure. This asked for a "flat" presentation of a three-way table, the sort of thing that is offered by the base ftable function which processes multi-way contingency tables.

Comment: Of course, there still might be a duplicate out there under the 'Liaw-Baron principle', but this is not it. `fortunes::fortune("Liaw-Baron"). I suppose there probably is a similar lemma for SO although the original was proposed in Rhelp.
`

Comment: @alistaire: In base R the `length` function was often used for the purpose to which hadleyversers now use `count`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(Survey), Age + Sex ~Health, value.var = "Country",
                   length)[, Total := Average + Good + Poor][]
```

---

If we don't want to type the column names, use `Reduce` with `+`

```
dcast(setDT(Survey), Age + Sex ~Health, value.var = "Country",
                length)[, Total := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols = Average:Poor][]
```

Comment: Thanks akrun...Is there a way to not type in the factor levels in the code? I am fine with not having grand total in the dataframe output. Sorry for the trouble and appreciate your blazing fast response!

Comment: @Jennifer Updated the post

Comment: voted both answers akrun :)...it doesn't show since so I dont have enough reputation it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `data.table` and `tidyr` but not `dcast`. First, you count observations with `.N` in `j` by the variables of interest

`Survey[, .N, by=.(Age, Sex, Health)]`

returning:

```
 Age   Sex     Health   N
 30-44 Female  Average  10
 65+   Female  Poor     9
 0-15  Male    Average  3
 16-29 Male    Average  6
 30-44 Male    Good     6
 45-64 Female  Average  8
```

Then, use `spread` from `tidyr` to turn your column of choice into a set of new columns (one for each unique value) populated by `N`

`spread(Survey[, .N, by=.(Age, Sex, Health)], Health, N)`

Comment: Thanks moman82...learned something new from all of you folks.